# getResources() return an error

Tags: java, android

I have error when using getRessources() to get values from string.xml.

Here my file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;


public class mailing extends Activity {
    int[] mail_images= new int[]{0, R.drawable.simple, R.drawable.p};
    String[] mail_array_spinner = new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.type_select),getResources().getString(R.string.maillist)};

    public int get_image_id(String check){
        int got=-1;

        for(int i=0;i<mail_images.length;i++){
            if(mail_array_spinner[i].equals(check)){
                got=i;
            }
        }
        return mail_images[got];
    }
}
```

My application stopped when reading the code and the error come form:

```
String[] mail_array_spinner = new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.type_select),getResources().getString(R.string.maillist)};
```

Here the log:

```
01-02 16:59:39.255 6087-6087/com.example.xx.cxeapp D/typei: mail
01-02 16:59:39.257 6087-6087/com.example.xx.cxeapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-02 16:59:39.258 6087-6087/com.example.xx.cxeapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.xx.cxeapp, PID: 6087
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
        at com.example.mouh.myapplication.mail.<init>(mail.java:11)
        at Adapters.InProgressListAdapter.getView(InProgressListAdapter.java:62)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1489)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:901)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1112)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:632)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
```

Any help to fix this issue please ? thanks.

Comment: What error ? We cannot fix what we cannot guess

Comment: Error it's the application stopped when reading GETRESSOURCE ! In log console say: FATAL EXCEPTION at line XX of my file ... at the line i specified above.

Comment: I just posted the logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Not same, if i found same question approch i was to read it there directly :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not written your code inside the `onCreate()`, do the following

```
    public class mailing extends Activity {
        int[] mail_images; 
        String[] mail_array_spinner;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mail_images= new int[]{0, R.drawable.simple, R.drawable.p};
            mail_array_spinner = new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.type_select),getResources().getString(R.string.maillist)};


    }

      public int get_image_id(String check){
            int got=-1;
            mail_images= new int[]{0, R.drawable.simple, R.drawable.p};
            mail_array_spinner = new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.type_select),getResources().getString(R.string.maillist)};
            for(int i=0;i<mail_images.length;i++){
                if(mail_array_spinner[i].equals(check)){
                    got=i;
                }
            }
            return mail_images[got];
        }
```

}

Comment: Thank for your answer, but when i made this changes, i got `get_image_id()` not recognized ! same as  `mail_images` and `mail_array_spinner`

Comment: Same thing :( i thing must be global or something like this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? You have not called the method `get_image_id()` to begin with.

Comment: the solution to fix it is to add: `int[] mail_images; 
String[] mail_array_spinner;` `before protected void onCreate` but doing this follow me to another error:  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

Comment: Yes the reason is that you are not calling your `get_image_id()` from your `onCreate()`.

Comment: In this file i dont have to call it, but this not resolved the problem as it return null and crash application.

Comment: i seen this,, but didn't solved the problem, return this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

Comment: Add most recent logcat.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array -  at com.example.sneh.myapplication.image_assoc.get_image_id(image_assoc.java:27)` here the logs - he point to this line: `for(int i=0;i<mail_images.length;i++){` and this because it's null value.

Comment: Things look fine to me.Make sure you have copy pasted the exact code that i have posted.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to call getResources() before your activity has been created, Which results in a null pointer exception. call getResources in the onCreate() method.

```
public class mailing extends Activity {
int[] mail_images; 
String[] mail_array_spinner; 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      mail_images  = new int[]{0, R.drawable.simple, R.drawable.p};
      mail_array_spinner =  new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.type_select),getResources().getString(R.string.maillist)};
    }
    public int get_image_id(String check){
        int got=-1;

        for(int i=0;i<mail_images.length;i++){
            if(mail_array_spinner[i].equals(check)){
                got=i;
            }
        }
        return mail_images[got];
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `public class mailing extends Activity` ?

Comment: Ok, posted complete answer

Comment: I just tried it but i have this error now: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array` ? any fix ?